# SQL Feature Not Supported Excpetion

Tags: java, mysql, exception, prepared-statement

I keep getting feature not supported exception with the following code:

```
public Collection<Product> getProds(String col, String prod) {
    LinkedList<Product> list = new LinkedList<>();
    try {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM Product where ? LIKE ?";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setString(1, col);
        ps.setString(1, prod);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(query);
        while ( rs.next() ) {
            Product product = new Product(
                    rs.getString("PID"),
                    rs.getString("Artist"),
                    rs.getString("Title"),
                    rs.getString("Description"),
                    rs.getInt("price"),
                    rs.getString("thumbnail"),
                    rs.getString("fullimage")
            );
            list.add( product );
        }
        return list;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println( "Exception in getProducts(): " + e );
        return null;
    }
}
```

I guess its something to do with the executeQuery. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set column name with PreparedStatement's `setString` method, you can only set the parameters.

If you don't know the column name, you can use Java String's `replace` method to specify the column name before creating PreparedStatement, e.g.:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Product where <column> LIKE ?";
query = query.replaceAll("<column>", col);

PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, prod);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Comment: that's giving me an unexpected token: < and says result of replaceAll is ignored

Comment: Ah okay, I have updated the answer. Actually, it needs to be `query = query.replaceAll("<column>", col);`

Comment: If you could delete the "query" in executeQuery at the end then I will as that bit needed changing too :)

Comment: Done, that was just a copy paste typo I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with PreparedStatements, but perhaps you have to do it like this:

```
    ps.setString(1, col);
    ps.setString(2, prod);
```

So that you define which parameter you want to set. Perhaps you set the first parameter twice at the moment and don't set the second parameter. In this example http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html they do it like this.

You also don't need to pass the query as parameter to the method `executeQuery()` because it will overwrite the already known query.

Comment: oh thats a problem I didn't see haha! Still get the same problem unfortunately

Comment: are you sure you have to give the query as parameter to the method executeQuery? Please try it without this parameter. The preparedStatement already knows your query. Perhaps your are searching know for the query with the two ? in it because you overwrite the query.

Comment: That was it! thank you so much, if you'd like to edit your answer I can mark it as solved

Comment: I edited my answer. So would be really nice if you mark it as solution. Thanks!